# How to change cisco 3750 specific port MTU to 9000?

Tags: switch, mtu

How to change cisco 3750 specific port MTU to 9000? I do not want to set it as a system global command for all ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, on the 3750, it's all or nothing.  You can't set individual ports.

Comment: Hi ron. Thanks. I need just some port with MTU 9000 because of vxlan. If I set all to 9000 what happen to my access switches that use trunk with 1500 MTU. what are pros and cons. Thank you